# (C/C++) Inline Assembly "add dword ptr [address]" increments the address instead of it's value

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline-assembly

I'm trying to increment the value at an address stored by a DWORD **iNumAddr** using Inline Assembly and I've noticed that it increments the address instead of the value it contains. Eg.

->**iNumAddr** = 57D03390

->**addstuff()** runs..

->**iNumAddr** = 57D033C2

The address is correct, I've tested it.

```
void addstuff()
{
    _asm {
        add dword ptr [iNumAddr], 50
    }
}
```

Comment: You're telling us how iNumAddr changes, but this code is adjusting iLiczbaAddr.  Can you show the surrounding code?

Comment: It's impossible for anything to change the address of a symbol during execution.  e.g. in C++ `int32_t iLiczbaAddr`, its address `&iLiczbaAddr` is constant throughout the life of the process.  You're definitely changing the value of the global variable `iLiczbaAddr`.  (If that value is a pointer, and you wanted to access the memory *it* points to, then of course you need to load it into a register first and deref that pointer.)

Comment: That's exactly what `dword ptr [variable]` does. It addresses `variable` itself, not the memory location pointed to by the value stored in `variable`. If you want the latter, you need to load `variable` to some register and use `dword ptr [<register>]`.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Sorry, iLiczbaAddr was meant to be iNumAddr, it is an error in this post only since I was changing variable names for simplicity.

Comment: @PeterCordes The thing is, this DWORD is a pointer and I'm incrementing the address it stores, not it's own physical address.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That was exactly what fixed it. I tried to load it into a register before but I must've made a mistake doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a variable `DWORD iNumAddr` in a high-level language such as C++, then the symbol `iNumAddr` in assembly-language code takes the value of the *address* of the high-level language variable `iNumAddr`. (This address is usually assigned by the linker.)

So the instruction `add dword ptr [iNumAddr], 50` will increment the variable `iNumAddr`, not the value that `iNumAddr` points to.

It takes two instructions to do what you want. For example:

```
mov ebx,[iNumAddr]
add dword ptr [ebx],50
```

Comment: Generally you'd want to pick a register like EAX that's call-clobbered, so MSVC might not have to save/restore it.  But if you're using MSVC inline asm at all for something like this, efficiency is clearly not your top goal.